# How do I preserve capitalization when using autocomplete in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, capitalization

How do I preserve capitalization when using the [Auto Complete extension](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) in emacs?

So that `example` cannot be completed as `Example` or `EXAMPLE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the setting I was looking for:

h(setq ac-ignore-case nil)